# get one value from xml document in php

Tags: php, xml

I have a php variable that contains xml code. I would like to get only one value from that xml and go along.

The xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <response> <status>SUCCESS</status> <data><count>1</count> <subscriberlist>     <item>          <subscriberid>4</subscriberid>          <emailaddress>bbbbbb@bbbbbb.bb</emailaddress>         <format>h</format>          <subscribedate>1314903006</subscribedate>          <confirmed>1</confirmed>          <unsubscribed>0</unsubscribed>          <bounced>0</bounced>          <listid>3</listid>     </item> </subscriberlist></data></response>
```

I would like to create the var $subscriberid and get the value (in this case 4)

Can someone explain me?

Comment: This is too vague; what do you mean by "go along"?

Answer (score 2):

This doc on php.net will tell you how: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

For the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
   <status>SUCCESS</status>
   <data>
      <count>1</count>
      <subscriberlist>
         <item>
            <subscriberid>4</subscriberid>
            <emailaddress>bbbbbb@bbbbbb.bb</emailaddress>
            <format>h</format>
            <subscribedate>1314903006</subscribedate>
            <confirmed>1</confirmed>
            <unsubscribed>0</unsubscribed>
            <bounced>0</bounced>
            <listid>3</listid>
         </item>
      </subscriberlist>
   </data>
</response>
```

If the xml was inside of `$xmlstr` then to get the subscriberid you would need the following php code:

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$subscriberid = $xml->data->subscriberlist->item->subscriberid;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) then parse the data

```
<?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml vers...');

    $subscriberid = $xml->data->subscriberlist->item->subscriberid;

?>
```